# efcore zero to one relationship cascade from principal

Tags: ef-core-2.0

in efcore 2.0 I'm trying to figure out how to configure this:

let say I have two table `Upload` and `BlogPost` and some more table that save their upload URL into upload. so the `upload` table doesn't need to have a FK to any other table that wants to save into it

```
class Upload{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string FileName{get;set;}
    public string SavedPath{get; set;}
}

//but each blog post need to know about its own upload
class BlogPost{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Content { get; set; }
    public Upload Upload { get; set; }
}
```

according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#definition-of-terms), any table that holds the FK is the dependant and any table that hold the primary key is the principal.

but in this case, the `BlogPost` is the principal and `Upload` is the dependent. if I delete the `BlogPost` then the upload must delete, not the otherwise.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPost>(b=>{
    b.HasOne(bp=>bp.Upload).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
})
```

according to `OnDelete` document, it delete the dependant if the the **principal** deleted, that in my case should be `BlogPost`, but because the Upload is not carrying any FK, efcore apply cascade wrongly.

my question is how do i make the efcore to get the BlogPost as the principal? or how should i approach this kind of scenario?

Comment: So you read and understand the documentation saying that the table with the FK is the dependent, and then contrary to that say that you want your table holding the FK to be the principal. Apparently this is not gonna happen. This is not EF Core concept, but how relational database relationships (with or w/o cascade) work.

Comment: @IvanStoev so how to handle this kind of case?